# Deployment issues to win phone 8.1 device

Tags: windows-phone-8, win-phone-silverlight-8.1

I am trying to deploy win. phone 8.1 app to device.But its throwing below error
My device is unlocked and I have valid developer account with MS. Also I have updated publisher id from my account for packing the app.

Error:

> Error 1   Error : DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: Package could not be
>   registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CF6)  App1

Answer (score 0):

This error generally comes if you have added any capability to the project which is not supported by OS version or any reference is added to the project which is not available. Check these things. If you are not sure which capability might be causing this problem you can comment out doubtful capabilities one by one and try to deploy.